# MySql sever instance configuration wizard help

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database

I have uninstalled mysql from my system long ago and i have forgot the passowrd i have set to mysql

now when i tried to install it its asking for the old password to set the new password in MySql sever instance configuration wizard

i am not getting access to mysql command line client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: i followed the instructions in the link
when i executed the following command 

 C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt

im getting this error

100710 14:38:27 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be re
moved in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') 
    WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```